# [Javascript][jQuery] Bind object with the jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a problem - would like the method to be attached on the prototype chain of Jquery Ajax fn().

working example:

```
/**
 * @method {ajax} - execute ajax call
 * @param {string} url - target url
 * @param {object} opts - configuration object 
 */
function ajax(url, opts) {
    var defaultObj = {
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    };

    var opts = $.extend({}, defaultObj, opts);

    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: opts.type,
        data: opts.data,
        async: opts.async,
        success: opts.success,
        cache: opts.cache,
        contentType: opts.contentType,
        processData: opts.processData
    });
};
```

And this due to it's a Jquery method doesn't seem to work.

```
...
var opts = $.extend({}, defaultObj, opts);

    return $.ajax.prorotype.call(this, opts);
```

What was we can bind an additional object with a jQuery method?

Comment: why not use $.ajax(opts) ?

Comment: this is what have done in the working example

Comment: put this as an answer not a comment so will set one as resolved